# OpenSearch "no alive node found" error originated from curl errorno 6: getaddrinfo() thread failed to start

Tags: curl, opensearch

I am using a cronjob to execute quite a lot of requests on Opensearch. If the number of requests gets too high, i am getting the following error:
`no alive node found in your cluster` 
The health check which gets executed the moment an Exception is thrown reports the server health as green, so no problem there.
When tracing the error further down i am getting that the Error actually originates in Curl:

```
'curl' => 
            array (size=2)
              'errno' => int 6
              'error' => string 'getaddrinfo() thread failed to start
```

Unfortunately i havent found anything helping me any further. Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated!

I already asked my hoster if there are any limits on the request, which they said there are none. The health check also indicates that there is no problem with the server itself in the time the error is thrown.